# Understanding android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH uses

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-search

I am trying to figure out the use of `android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH` documentation does not provide any useful information.

What I am trying to achieve and where I am confused?

IMO this permission may allow the system app (that search widgets on launcher) to perform Global Search just like a search but for apps that expose a provider (search) like contacts, calendar, and more. Is this true? Or is it just a  deprecated permission that the Android team forgot to remove?

I am trying to make a system app that can query almost all of the data on the device like contacts, media, calendar, and provide a way to open that in a supported app like contact data in contact app (based on Authority of provider) is `android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH` something I can use or should I look for something else?

Thanks in advance for the help :)